# Problem with calculation Precision and Recall

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I could not calculate the precision and recall correctly in the code below:

Can you please help to fix the formula for them. Here is the code segment:

```
for epoch in range(2):  
    running_loss = 0.0
    training_accuracy = 0.0
    training_total = 0.0
    training_correct = 0.0
    ##########
    training_precision = 0.0
    training_recall = 0.0
    
    for i, data in enumerate(t_loader, 0):
      
        inputs, labels = data        
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        inputs = inputs.view(bs,1,28,28).float()
        outputs = cnn(inputs)
    
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1) 
        training_total = training_total + labels.size(0)
        training_correct = training_correct + (predicted == labels).sum().item() #accumulate correct
        ##########

        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()
        if i % 200 == 199:    
            training_accuracy=training_correct/training_total
            training_accuracy_list.append(training_accuracy)
            ##########
            training_precision = training_correct / (training_correct + labels.size(0))/220 
            training_recall = training_correct / (training_correct + (predicted != labels).sum().item() )/200
```

Comment: You are using `pytorch` not `keras`, so change the tag to `torch` or `pytorch`, If you really want others to solve your problem then I suggest you post some test code that everyone can run, otherwise there no way to debug it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your calculate the Precision and Recall is wrong, you shouldn't add all the true positive first, check out the right way to [calculate Precision and Recall for multi-class classification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51296/how-do-you-calculate-precision-and-recall-for-multiclass-classification-using-co)